# How to create get request with 3 parameters?

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to do this like this. But this give me the error :  Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
E/flutter (31038):  WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:242)) Host name have good name. It's a server.

This is my code. How to do this?

```
var queryParameters = {
            'abc': 'abc',
            'bcd': 'bcd,
            'cde' : 'cde'
          };
var uri = Uri.https('www.xyz.pl:1234', '/admin/api/get', queryParameters);
var response1 = await http.get(uri);
```

Comment: "wrong version number" probably means that the server is not an HTTPS server; perhaps you should use "http" as the scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo

```
var res = await http.get(
  Uri.encodeFull('www.xyz.pl'), 
  headers : queryParameters);
```

hardcoded

```
var res = await http.get(
  Uri.encodeFull('www.xyz.pl'), 
  headers : {
  "abc": "abc",
  "bcd": "bcd",
  "cde": "cde"
});

final statusCode = res.statusCode;
```

Explanation how to make authenticated requests here - https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/authenticated-requests

Answer (score 1):

```
var queryParameters = {
            'abc': 'abc',
            'bcd': 'bcd,
            'cde' : 'cde'
          };

var uri ='www.xyz.pl:1234/admin/api/get';  // your url

bool trustSelfSigned = true;

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()
      ..badCertificateCallback =
      ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => trustSelfSigned);
IOClient ioClient = new IOClient(httpClient);

await ioClient.get(Uri.parse(uri), body: queryParameters).then((response) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
         print(response);
       }
```

Try this code

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Map<String, String> headers, body, encoding` for pass multiple reguest  param. You can check it [here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/01/flutter-get-and-post-http-requests.html).